# plotly contour plot with animation

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

### Problem

I'm attempting to animate a **scatter/contour** plot using **Plotly**. I've managed to animate the scatter plot, however, when attempting to include any contour, it disappears immediately after initiating the animation. If possible, I would like the contour to be visible throughout the animation.

For context, the plot is meant to visualise a parameter optimisation algorithm. However, since the actual data here isn't relevant, I've attempted to recreate the problem below using the gapminder dataset.

---

### Code

*This code is just for demonstration purposes and simply recreates the contour disappearing effect.*

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

df = px.data.gapminder()
df['gdpPercap'] = df['gdpPercap'] / 1000

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
                 size="pop", color="continent", size_max=55, range_x=[0.01,100], range_y=[25,90])

fig.add_trace(go.Contour(z=np.random.uniform(0,5,size=[75, 100]), y = np.arange(25, 90, 5)))

fig.show()
```

---

### Questions

From the Plotly website, their [Intro to Animations](https://plot.ly/python/animations/) states that.

> Defining redraw: Setting `redraw: false` is an optimization for scatter
>   plots so that animate just makes changes without redrawing the whole
>   plot. For other plot types, such as contour plots, every frame must be
>   a total plot redraw, i.e. `redraw: true`.

1. I'm having difficulty finding where to define `redraw: true`.
2. Is this possible using `plotly.express`?